# Difference between this operators

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

Which is the difference between this operators, acting over a mangitude $A(x,x',t)$?

a)

- $ \delta A/ \delta x$
- $dA/dx$

b)

- $ \delta A/ \delta x$
- $\partial A/\partial x$

often used is physics?

Comment: In terms of two dimensions, it doesn't really matter what you use.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\delta A / \delta x$?

Comment: I must add, in physics one often uses $\delta A$ to indicate this is not an "exact differential".

Comment: @Ranc and which is the exact meaning of $\delta A$? Thank you

Comment: @Ranc for example, if $\vec{r}$ is the position vector, what does $\delta \vec{r}$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference in either case.

Typically, one uses $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ when one thinks of $A$ as a function of multiple variables, with $x$ being merely one of those variables. On the other hand, one uses $\frac{d}{dx}$ when one thinks of $A$ as a function of a single variable, perhaps holding the other parts constant.

For instance, consider the polynomial $p(x, a, b) = ax + b$. Then
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = a$$
and
$$ \frac{dp}{dx} = a.$$
But in the latter, we are thinking of $a$ and $b$ as being fixed constants.

It should be noted however that many authors ignore or abuse this convention, so it is necessary to infer specific meaning from context.